# How to make \mathbf robust?

Tags: arrays, robust-commands, fragile

I made a command `\statementinput` which makes a table easily with given two lists of elements. Most of the elements are math formulas, and I don't want to put each of them in `\(\)`, so I used the `array` environment inside `\[\]`.

When I used `\mathrm` in an element, it gave errors. I thought the reason is that `\mathrm` is fragile, so I added `\robustify{\mathrm}` and everything seemed fine.

Now I need to use `\mathbf`. Still `\robustify{\mathbf}` works, but now using `\(\mathbf{A}\)` in a normal place does not work, giving an error `Use of \reserved@a doesn't match its definition. \(\mathbf{A}`. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\statementapp}{m m m m}{%
    \def\rowAname{#1}%
    \def\rowBname{#2}%
    \def\listA{#3}%
    \def\listB{#4}%
    \newcount\listlen
    %
    \let\arraycontent\empty
    \xappto\arraycontent{\text{\rowAname}}
    \foreach \Ae in \listA {%
        \xappto\arraycontent{& \Ae}%
    }%
    \gappto\arraycontent{\\ \hline}
    \xappto\arraycontent{\text{\rowBname}}
    \foreach \Be [count=\n] in \listB {%
        \xappto\arraycontent{& \Be}%
        \global\let\listlen\n
    }%
    \[%
    \begin{array}{|r<{\hspace{0.3pc}}|*{\listlen}{>{\hspace{0.3pc}}l|}}
        \hline
        \arraycontent \\
        \hline
    \end{array}\]%
}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\statementinput}{m m}{%
    \statementapp{Parameters}{Playing the role of}
    {#1}{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\oo}{{\mathrm{o}}}

\robustify{\mathrm}
\robustify{\mathbf}



\begin{document}

\statementinput{\mathrm{Ab}Cd, 2}{B^\oo,4}
\statementinput{\mathbf{Ab}Cd, 2}{B^\oo,4} 

%\(\mathbf{A}\) % does not work

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the MWE]

Comment: Do not use \xappto if you handle arbitrary input, that is bound to break somewhere (untested, but here probably at the line break), and do not allocate a count inside a definition body).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I used `\xappto` because I wanted for example `\Ae` to be expanded when I append it to `\arraycontent`. What should I use instead?

Comment: with a current latex something like this `\gappto\arraycontent{&}\ExpandArgs{No}\gappto\arraycontent{\Be}`. With older latex you need a bunch of \expandafter to control the expansion.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong tools.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\statementapp}{mmmm}
 {
  \greatseo_statementapp:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \greatseo_statementapp:nnnn
 {
  \begin{tabular}
   {
    |r<{\hspace{0.3pc}}|*{\clist_count:n { #3 }}{>{\hspace{0.3pc}$}l<{$}|}
   }
  \hline
  #1 & \clist_use:nn { #3 } { & } \\
  \hline
  #2 & \clist_use:nn { #4 } { & } \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\statementinput}{m m}{%
    \statementapp{Parameters}{Playing the role of}
    {#1}{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\oo}{{\mathrm{o}}}

\begin{document}

\statementinput{\mathrm{Ab}Cd, 2}{B^\oo,4}

\medskip

\statementinput{\mathbf{Ab}Cd, 2}{B^\oo,4}

\medskip

\statementinput{\mathbf{Ab}Cd, 2, 3, 4}{B^\oo,4,5,6}

\end{document}
```

[image]